# Mixing/Mastering headroom

Tags: mixing, mastering

I understand that headroom is needed between the mixing and mastering processes.  For example, after a mix is done it may sit at -6dB so the person mastering the song has headroom to play with.

I have heard that if you send a slightly-below 0dB track to a masterer they will tell you to fix it and send it back to them with more headroom. That makes sense as they need headroom to play with.

I am trying to figure out if there's any difference between mixing something to -6dB and sending it to a masterer or mixing something to slightly-below 0dB and having the masterer pull the volume fader on the track down by -6dB to compensate.

I'd think that there'd be no difference, but I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about that. So, is there a difference and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: "I have heard that" where? Please provide citations.

Comment: numerous videos and online tutorials. Sorry but I prefer not to detract from the main question with tons of links.

Comment: Well, imo the main question is based on a false premise - so having some background as to where the information came from might give us a hint as to how you arrived at the false premise.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but I don't want to hunt down links. So your answer is that it is a false premise and there's no difference.

Comment: Don't worry about the difference between 0 dBFS and the peak level of your mix, worry about the difference between the peak level of your mix and the *averaage* level of your mix. That's the *crest factor*. Don't compress away your crest factor, and find or get a metering plugin or meters in your DAW that will show you both the average and peak levels of your mix, so you know what your crest factors are when you are mixing. Crest factors around 15 - 21 dB are good.

Comment: One other thing about my comment, if the mastering engineer either raises or lowers the total gain on your mix, then that doesn't change the crest factor of your mix, so again, you want to worry about your crest factor, not your peak level. Note that the first sentence of your question doesn't really make sense. I think you've got a problem where you haven't learned enough about audio engineering to be able to even ask about what you're trying to understand.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin, it would help to see an example of what you're reading that talks about a mix "sitting at -6 dB so the mastering engineer has 'headroom'", because that could mean several different things and it's not clear what you're asking about. Normally, **no** mix would "sit at -6 dB". If "sit at" means peak levels, then -6 dB is unnecessarily low - might as well make then between -1 and -3 dB. If "sit at" means average levels, then -6 dB is **way** too high. If the crest factor is more than 12 dB, then it doesn't matter where the peaks are (within reason).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a slew of miscomprehension as to why mixing to -6dB is a good or bad idea. Let me throw in some quick persuasion as to why this is 'a false premise'.

1. If you mix to -6dB you immediately add 6dB of random noise to your noise floor. You've just thrown those extra bits away, wasted them for no reason.
2. The amount of compression does not change your resulting headroom.
   Over-compressing the mix is going to annoy the mastering engineer no matter how many dBFS you leave him at the top.
   You've already crushed the life out of it & he has nothing to work with. This is the same whether you hit -0.01dB or -18dB.
3. The Mastering engineer wants **clean**. He wants **breathing room**.
   He wants headroom in the actual audio, not in the final level.
   'Clean' is achieved by not doing 1, or 2. above.
4. If you were to save your mix at 32-bit float then minor considerations aside [rounding, floating point error I'm going to ignore just for this one purpose] then you could send your mix at +18dB & it wouldn't make the slightest difference.
5. We no longer in this digital era have a compulsory 'absolute' 0dB before the track is mastered for the consumer. We have floating point internally, we only go to fixed point at output. At that point what we do have these days, to combat the Loudness War, is we have LUFS. [I'm not going to explain LUFS, Google it :P]
   LUFS, however, is held as 'the ultimate weapon' by Apple Music, Spotify, YouTube etc.
   This is [as we're down to fixed decimal point sound at consumer level] bounded by our 0dBFS, but weighted to an average 'loudness', which these broadcasters will not let us exceed… if you do, they'll just turn your whole track down.
   This bit is the mastering engineer's concern.

So, in conclusion…
Mix to -0.01 dBFS if you want, or leave a comfortable 0.3dB if it makes you happier. Your DAW metering will be able to spot any real overs.
Don't comp the sh*t out of it. This will irritate the mastering engineer & he will either do a bad job or send it back to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation you provided. I guess I should be more clear. Instead of mixing I should say leveling as I was not intending to say I'd compress anything (as I'd leave that to mastering)

Comment: What is mixing if it doesn't involve 'levelling'? You **do** need to comp unless you're doing classical or jazz. **How** you comp is all a part of the mix engineer's job. The mastering engineer is the guy with the golden ears who turns your mix into something fit to be released. He is not going to do the mix for you. That's your job.

Comment: I guess I'm used to seeing compression plugins on the masterers side (as well as the mixers). I guess it needs to be done in both places, with the mindset to not squash it completely in the mix before giving it to the masterer

Comment: Now you're getting the idea ;) You need to leave the mastering engineer **breathing room**. This not the same as wasting 6dB at the top.

Comment: There is a thing called inter-sample overs, but since AFAIK they only occur in actual playback/listening, you don't need to avoid them in the mixdown if you're not doing the final master. Right?

Comment: So to further clarify, each individual track should have headroom in mixing b/c something like eq/compression/effects/plugins can spike it up too high and/or squash it. The master fader should be set as close to 0dB as possible to reduce unwanted noise before rendering to a stereo file for the masterer. Sound about right?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - tbh, I've personally always used -0.3dB & a brick-wall limiter right at the final output to avoid these, in both mix & mastering stages & have never had anyone mention I got stray overs. I haven't studied that part to the *n*th degree, so really can't say for sure.

Comment: This is all pretty much 'artistic expression' but you can comp any & all parts of a track or a mix to achieve your 'glue', but if you aim for 'what you hear on the radio with a pop song' you've probably already over-cooked it. this is something you just have to try out. The first time you ever hear your mix on the radio will be the first time you ever get to know if you really got it right. [Modern plugins have 'radio' emulators to help you with this.]

Comment: And just so I understand, there IS a difference between rendering a stereo file at -6dB and having the masterer up the fader by 6dB to compensate and just rendering a stereo file to just before 0dB and having the masterer do nothing to compensate. And that difference is unwanted noise? If that's true then isn't there noise between whatever the mix is and upping the level on the master fader before rendering to a stereo file?  I think that's where I'm confused

Comment: We're now getting into the realms of gain-staging & going far beyond the remit of the original question. Just bear in mind that any mix operation needs a calculation. Every calculation makes the sound 'dirtier' by some infinitesimal degree. Your job is to reduce these as much as you can, whilst mainly just ignoring what goes on inside the DAW, which probably works at 64-bit floating point to reduce this calculation error so far as to make it negligible… you only need to worry at output.

Comment: In other words (extreme example) , let's say the cumulative output of all tracks combined is -12dB. Would I up the master fader by about that much, or would I up each individual track until the cumulative is closer to 0dB? And if I did tha, wouldn't I squash the headroom from the individual tracks?

Comment: So without gain staging, are the 2 scenarios equivalent in terms of noise? Masterer uses fader post-render vs mixer uses fader pre-render?

Comment: Too many questions. Sorry, but we're way past answering your question now & into the entire theory of 'how to record & mix'. Far too broad for anyone to deal with, & especially not in comments. Subscribe to a magazine like Sound On Sound, do some real long-term research. This is a topic that takes **years** to get to grips with.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I think I got a starting point going forward here: https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/gain-staging-what-it-is-and-how-to-do-it.html

Comment: I'm assuming the asker is a bit confused about these things, so I suggest making it clear what you mean by "mixing to -6 dB". I would normally guess that means mixing so that the average level of the mix is -6 dB, but that would be a very hot, compressed mix, so I wouldn't expect there to be much discussion about "mixing to -6 dB" other than "don't do that, target your average levels somewhere between -21 and -12 dB". So maybe you're talking about mixing so that the peaks are around -6 dB? Nothing wrong with that, but maintaining a crest factor is what you want in any case.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the videos/threads etc don't specify those things and I am new at this so I'm sure I was off in the understanding and translations somewhere along the line

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that some of the tracks on an album spend most of their time at an amplitude which is 1dB below the peak amplitude, and others spend most of their time 5dB below the peak amplitude.  If one were to start by mixing the first group of tracks with a peak amplitude of 0dB, there would be no way to avoid having the tracks in that group sound louder than tracks in the second group except by cutting the volume on them.  If one were to instead start by mixing the first group of tracks with a main amplitude of -6dB, peaking at -5dB, then one could mix the second group with the same main amplitude, letting it peak at -1dB.

I don't think there's anything particularly special about -6dB as a value except that it's large enough to accommodate many scenarios but small enough not to cause too much needless loss of signal quality.  Different genres of music benefit from different amounts of headroom, and how the dynamic range of the piece being mixed is expected to compare with that of other pieces that will be mixed.